# PHP Form - Email sent doesn't support characters

Tags: php, forms, iso-8859-1, latin

I have a contact page (contact.php) that sends a form (formsend.php) when people fill in the contact details.

The contact.php has:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

Contact.php page is fine, displays my latin Portuguese characters fine (ã, é, etc).

But when I receive the email (when it uses formsend.php), I get the fields people signed up with messed up characters: João is JoÃ£o, etc.

On formsend.php I've tried adding:

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

and

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

as well. Nothing works.

It seems it's the formsend.php file that is failing here.

What can I do to ensure I receive properly formatted characters in the email with the user's info?

Comment: switch the email encoding to utf8.

Comment: @Dagon - it utf-8 is even worse. Characters are not recognizable in either contact.php or sendform.php :(

Comment: header() is only going to affect the output from server->browser. It will do absolutely **NOTHING** to the email that gets sent from the script.

Comment: @Marc B what do you suggest then?

Comment: Bite the bullet, switch to using UTF-8 throughout your entire pipeline: web pages, database tables/fields, database connection, blah blah blah. if you use a different charset at ANY point in the pipeline, you're going to get corrupted characters.

Comment: You may have a `BOM` issue. Consult => http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bom/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you may try to switch utf-8:
and also do not forget to change header info 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
but also you need to convert user inputed text to utf-8 in this case you will have no problem... I had the same problem with Armenian...

Comment: I've put header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); in sendform.php - it didn't work. All people I talk to suggest the same (headers, utf-8), but I don't know why it isn't working. By the way the contact.php needs to have the  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> or it will not show any latin characters on the contact page form. Contact.php page is good, I only have a problem with sendform.php (sending emails I receive them with the funny characters).

Comment: it is more better to convert only the user input to utf-8: after word add it in an html file witch header <meta charset="utf-8"> and aferwords save the wholl page in a string and give it as an email content...

Comment: you also will need to change the file encription in your IDE... if you tell me what IDE you are using I will be able to help you... after this step it will work normally